# Require_once não esta conseguindo acessar arquivo

Tags: php, html, orientação-a-objetos

Não estou conseguindo incluir páginas ao meu arquivo `controle_login.php`, pois gera os seguintes erros:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant ABSPATH - assumed 'ABSPATH' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Modelo_MVC\controlles\controle_login.php on line 2

> Warning: require_once(ABSPATH/models/model_login): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Modelo_MVC\controlles\controle_login.php on line 2

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'ABSPATH/models/model_login' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Modelo_MVC\controlles\controle_login.php on line 2

Vou postar os códigos, pois tem semanas que eu não consigo entender o que esta havendo.

**Arquivo config.php**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Arquivo index.php**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Arquivo **controle_login.php** (este arquivo esta dentro de uma pasta chamada controlles)

```
<?php
require_once ABSPATH.'/models/model_login.php';

class Controlador extends Controle_login{

    public function __construct(){
        $obj = new Controle_login;
    }
```

Arquivo **model_login.php** (este arquivo esta dentro da pasta models)

```
<?php
require_once ABSPATH.'conexao.php';

class Controle_login{

    private $con;

    public function __construct {
        $con = new Conexao();
    }

    public function controle_acesso($usuario, $senha){
        $this->setUsuario($usuario);
        $this->setSenha($senha);

        $consulta = $this->con->conectar()->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM login WHERE usuario=:usuario AND senha=:senha");
        $consulta->bindParam(":usuario", $this->usuario);
        $consulta->bindParam(":senha", $this->senha);
        $consulta->execute();
        $linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $linha['total'];
    }

}
```

**Estrutura de pastas:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro ocorre porque a variável `ABSPATH` esta sendo declarada dentro do arquivo `config.php`, então, para você utiliza-la dentro de outros arquivos é necessário carregar o arquivo `config.php` antes.

Como as suas pastas `controllers` e `models` estão no mesmo diretório que o arquivo `config.php` você pode realizar a importação da seguinte forma antes de usar a constante `ABSPATH`:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__)."/../config.php";
```

Por exemplo, o seu arquivo `controle_login.php` ficaria assim:

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__)."/../config.php";
require_once ABSPATH.'/models/model_login.php';

class Controlador extends Controle_login{

    public function __construct(){
        $obj = new Controle_login;
    }
```

> OBS: Os `..`(dois pontos) no caminho do diretório tem a função de
>   voltar uma pasta.

Comment: Fiz exatamente como você me explicou e deu certo :) Obrigada pela ajuda