# Use of undefined constant

Tags: php, require

Bom estava com o mesmo problema [dessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/180845/erro-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory) pergunta, deram uma resposta para usar `define('ROOT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));`, ([meu problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/316534/problema-com-require-once?noredirect=1#comment640522_316534) sem usar essa solução) porém no meu não funciona. 
É apresentado o seguinte erro:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant DIRETORIO - assumed 'DIRETORIO' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\wamp64\www\php_pdo\view\sign-in.php on line 27

index.php:

```
    <php   
    define('DIRETORIO', dirname(__DIR__));
    ...
```

sign-in.php:

```
<?php
    if($_POST){
        $usuario = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'usuario', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $senha = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'senha', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        require_once DIRETORIO . '/controller/logincontroller.php'; // linha 27
        LoginController::logar($usuario, $senha);

    }
```

Tentei fazer o que [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/270811/require-once-n%C3%A3o-esta-conseguindo-acessar-arquivo?rq=1) sugere, mas deu no mesmo.

sign-in.php

```
<?php
    if($_POST){
        $usuario = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'usuario', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $senha = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'senha', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        require_once '../index.php';
        require_once DIRETORIO . '/controller/logincontroller.php'; // linha 27
        LoginController::logar($usuario, $senha);

    }
```

Comment: Não basta adicionar a constante em um arquivo, é necessário utilizar o `require` para incluir o arquivo com a constante no aruqivo `sign-in.php`. Evite utilize `../index.php` ou similar, dê preferência em utilizar o caminho completo do arquivo `/path/to/index.php` ou `c:/path/to/index.php`

Comment: Obrigado, pensei que as variáveis criadas por `define` eram globais.